# Como criar um método assíncrono que seja cancelável?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo

Como criar um método assíncrono que seja cancelável?

Nesse contexto, o método `DoFoo()` faz coisas que não podem ser simplesmente paradas, como leitura e gravação de arquivos, e ao cancelar, tenho que esperar que essas operações de I/O sejam concluídas para o método ser cancelado.

```
private async void Button_Click()
{
    await DoFoo();
}

private async void Cancelar_Click()
{
    // cancelamento do método DoFoo()
    // ...
}

private async Task DoFoo()
{
    // operações de I/O
    File.WriteAllText("path", "conteudo");

    // operações de longa execução

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Depende do que está executando, precisa ter a oportunidade de executar o cancelamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisa criar um *token* de cancelamento no método. Só pode cancelar o que está preparado para o cancelamento. De forma geral a API assíncrona do .NET aceita.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void Button_Click() {
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try {
        await DoFoo(cts.Token);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
        //trata o cancelamento
    }
}

private async void Cancelar_Click() => cts.Cancel();

private async Task DoFoo(CancellationToken ct) {
    // operações de I/O
    File.WriteAllText("path", "conteudo");
    for (var item in lista) {
        //faz o que quiser aqui
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //isto pode ser muito lento
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/Cancelable.cs).

É comum não verificar se houve pedido de cancelamento em cada passo do *loop* já que a verificação tem um custo razoável, então pode filtrar quando aceitar uma requisição de cancelamento, talvez a cada 1000 itens processados, por exemplo.

Certamente tem outras formas de fazer dependendo do objetivo. Exceção não precisa ser o mecanismo de tratamento.

Documentação do [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

[Documentação do `CancellationToken`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).